# What does "such things" refer to in Hebrews 11:14

Tags: greek, word-study, hebrews, authorial-intent

> For they that say **such things** declare plainly that they seek a
>   country. [Hebrews 11:14](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/11-14.htm)

What does **such things** refer to? How and where did they say **such things**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the phrase «οἱ γὰρ τοιαῦτα λέγοντες»—“For those who say such things,” the word τοιαῦτα refers to the **confessions** (cf. 11:13) of all those who died in faith that “they are strangers and pilgrims on earth.”